# How to get documentum repository names?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, documentum, dfc

I am new in Documentum and Oracle. I want to get repository names. In Webtop login window repositories displays with description, but in database repositories named like DREPN3.  Now, i need to get list of repositories like

- drepn3 | Natural Resources
- drepn4 | Employment
- drepn6 | Energrtics

Comment: Are you trying to query the database for the name of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing your own Documetnum client you would do something like this using DFC:

```
IDfClient dfClient = new DfClientX().getLocalClient();
IDfDocbaseMap dfDocbaseMap = dfClient.getDocbaseMap();
for (int i = 0; i < dfDocbaseMap.getDocbaseCount(); i++) {
    String docbaseName = dfDocbaseMap.getDocbaseName(i);
    String docbaseDescription = dfDocbaseMap.getDocbaseDescription(i);

    //... do your thing for each pair docbaseName, docbaseDescription; eg.
    System.out.println(docbaseName + " | " + docbaseDescription);
}
```

I suggest you dig a bit through Documentum API (DFC) like [here](http://www.nathanobert.com/dfc7/index.html?overview-summary.html)